# Android: Sometime views are drawn as empty rectangles

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources

Most of the time views are displayed correctly, but sometimes they are displayed as empty spaces.

This is the code I use to generate a dialog. Both the title and the message are sometimes displayed as white rectangles (I assume it's because I use the light theme, otherwise I think they would be black).

```
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setTitle(R.string.warning);
    b.setMessage(R.string.want_to_close);
    b.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, ...);
    b.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, ...);
    b.show();
```

Comment: What language are you using? Are you using an unsupported character set?

Comment: Language is slovenian, XML encoding is UTF-8

Comment: You made me think. I will try to replace all the special characters in the xml with character codes

Answer (score 0):

To display Alert message, please refer the following,

**Alert(getString(R.string.warning),getString(R.string.want_to_close));**

```
public void Alert(String text, String title)
    { 
        AlertDialog dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(text);
        if(!title.equals("") && !text.equals(""))
        {
            dialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                            //Do anything
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setButton2("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                             //Do anything
                        }
                    });
        }

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: title and text are not empty, they are in the strings.xml.

Comment: you can pass, R.string.warning as title,R.string.want_to_close as message

Comment: The view inside the dialog itself displays as a white empty rectangle, but not always. Most of the time it displays just fine

Comment: did you called as " Alert(getString(R.string.warning),getString(R.string.msg));". It is working for me. Check the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `Alertdialog` object from the `Builder` and then show.

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
b.setTitle(R.string.warning);
b.setMessage(R.string.want_to_close);
b.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, ...);
b.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, ...);

AlertDialog alert = b.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: you can skip the create() it displays anyway